# Dynamic Cascading Dropdown Lists in ASP.NET Web Forms issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have three cascading dropdown lists that form a hierarchy, once the client select a location from the locations list, all building related to it are loaded in the buildings list, and once the client selects a building, all units related to it are loaded in the units list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onqJI.png)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocationDetail" class="form-control form-control-select2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuildingDetail" class="form-control form-control-select2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUnitDetail" class="form-control form-control-select2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to load the data of each field upon selection of its parent field dynamicly without refresh postback

I've tried that using the following:

1. UpdatePanel
2. AJAX

UpdatePanel loads the values the intended way, but they mess up the page somehow (I'm not sure how exactly but the styles of some compnents go missing, for example the multi select styles disappear and intl-tel-input country flag disappears ).

AJAX loads the values in the list perfecly and the page styles are intact, but when I submit the form, the server side sees the buildings and units list as empty with no selected values (even though on the client side the lists are filled and the values are selected correctly.

I can't find any of them to work.

here is the js code for refrence

```js
function FillBuildingsByLocation(userDataBase, ddlLocation, ddlBuildings, ddlUnits) {
    ddlLocation.change(function () {
        var locationId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MasterData/GetBuildingsByLocationId',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { locationId: locationId, userDataBase: userDataBase },
            success: function (data) {
                ddlBuildings.empty();
                ddlUnits.empty();
                addFirstSelect(ddlBuildings)
                $(data).each(function () {
                    $(document.createElement('option')).val(this.id).text(this.name).appendTo(ddlBuildings);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading buildings!");
            }
        });
    });
}

function FillUnitsByBuilding(userDataBase, ddlBuildings, ddlUnits) {

    ddlBuildings.change(function () {
        var buildingId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/MasterData/GetUnitsByBuildingId',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { buildingId: buildingId, userDataBase: userDataBase },
            success: function (data) {
                ddlUnits.empty();
                addFirstSelect(ddlUnits)
                $(data).each(function () {
                    $(document.createElement('option')).val(this.id).text(this.name).appendTo(ddlUnits);
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading units!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a simple cascade with server side code is 100% dead simple, and 100% reliable.

However, as you state (and you not expanded much as to why), that you don't really want a page post-back. And to be fair, there are boatloads of reasons for that goal. (often we don't want a post-back for many reasons).

However, I suspect that you leaving out VERY significant details here.

For example:

> for example the multi select styles disappear

HOLD ON!!!! Dropdown lists are NOT mutli-select. So, are you using a 3rd party script library to enable and allow multi-select dropdowns? I mean, that is HUGE news here. You can say that you came to my farm, and borrowed a rope. However, leaving out the details that my 3 prized cows were attached to the rope is a big detail, and one that you can't leave out!!!

So, some cascade dropdowns? Sure, place those dropdowns in a update panel.

Say like this:

```
<h4>Region</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRegion" runat="server"
        DataTextField="Region"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        Width="150px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>Country</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCountry" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="Country" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        Width="250px"  >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

And code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT region from vRegion ORDER BY region");
        DataTable rstData;
        rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboRegion.DataSource = rstData;
        cboRegion.DataBind();
        cboRegion.Items.Insert(0,"Select Region");
    }


    protected void cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboRegion.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            string strSQL =
                @"SELECT Country FROM vCountryRegion
                WHERE region = @region
                ORDER BY Country";

            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboRegion.Text;
            DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
            cboCountry.DataSource = rstData;
            cboCountry.DataBind();
            cboCountry.Items.Insert(0, "Select Country");
        }
    }
```

So, we now have/get this:

[image]

And above works JUST fine in a update panel.

However, note VERY close how we ALWAYS for EVERY page that you have?

You need to test and use the !IsPostBack flag for the first "real" page load.

Keep in mind that a update panel while not a full page post-back?

It does trigger the standard page lifecycle. And that includes a trigger of the page load event.

So, any code to load up any control, and especially a combo box? Well, the user's choice will be lost and overwritten if you LOAD UP EACH time the combo box, since that page load event runs BEFORE the event stub for a button or in this case the combo box.

And that means for the last 200+ web pages I have used (regardless of update panel or not), then your FIRST load code MUST be placed in that !IsPostBack stub. If you don't follow this rule, then you really can create a working webform.

So, unless you provide more details, then a update panel should not mess up your page, but of course I suspect there are some HUGE details you have left out here.

So, keep in mind that with a update panel, the page load event DOES trigger and run each time for any update panel that posts-back the update panel.

## Edit: Working example with using select2.js multi-select

First up, I am "somewhat" perplexed how WITHOUT a update panel, that a dropdown list can be mutli-select AND ALSO cascade? That setup can be made to work as I will show below.

And in my comments I well noted that with JUST a udpate panel, then I suspected that the page "on ready" in js to loadup, setup, maintain and run the select2 multi-select probably fails, and the REASON is of course the page on-ready client side HAS to run each time to matintain, and do all that fancy foot work EACH time to keep that dropwodn list working.

And worse yet?
Select2.js does NOT play nice with a dropdown list. So, the soluion is to use a standard HTML select element, and simple toss in a runat="server" to make it behave "somewhat" like a asp.net server side Dropdown list.

Worse yet? Well of course a standard "select" element does NOT have a auto-post back, and I assume for cascade to work, we need that!!

So, I fake auto-postback with a button click (and we hide the display of the button).

So, in this example, the first combo is to select the city. You can select one city, or many. As you select each city, then the 2nd combo box (of hotels) then casades and displays all the hotels from the current list of city(s) selected.

So, now we have this markup:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div style="float: left">
                    <h4>Select Multiple Cites</h4>
                    <select id="DropDownList1" runat="server"
                        multiple="true"
                        datatextfield="City"
                        style="width: 460px"
                        onchange="mychange()">
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 25px">
                    <h4>Select Hotel</h4>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"
                        DataValueField="ID"
                        DataTextField="HotelName"
                        Style="width: 260px; height: 32px; font-size: larger">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <script>
            function mychange() {
                $('#Button1').click()
            }

            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(runafterup);

            function runafterup() {
                // the select2 code needs to run AFTER the UP round trip
                // and content comes back - no document ready will run/fire
                $('#DropDownList1').select2();
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#DropDownList1').select2();
                console.log("on page run")
            });


        </script>
```

And our code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()
    ' load first combo
    Dim rstHotels As DataTable
    rstHotels = MyRst("SELECT City FROM tblHotels
                       WHERE City is not null
                       GROUP BY City")

    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstHotels.Rows
        Dim nItem As New ListItem(OneRow("City"))
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(nItem)
    Next

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' the button click (to cascade to 2nd combo)
    ' this button used in place of auto-postback
    Dim sList As String = ""
    For Each nItem As ListItem In DropDownList1.Items
        If nItem.Selected Then
            If sList <> "" Then sList &= ","
            sList &= $"'{nItem.Text}'"
        End If
    Next

    If sList <> "" Then
        Dim strSQL As String =
            $"SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels
            WHERE City in ({sList}) ORDER BY HotelName"

        DropDownList2.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        DropDownList2.DataBind()
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel")

    End If

End Sub
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, as I suspected and stated in the comments. Using a update panel means the client side js "on page ready" does not fire when you use a update panel, and of course select2.js library does a boatload of stuff to setup the dropdown, and does this EACH TIME.  So, note the extra code to run that select2.js code EACH time after the update panel makes it round trip.

Comment: thank you for your extensive answer Albert and apologies on my part if my intentions was vague, i didn't want to cluter the question with useless information.

Anyway, here is a representation of the issue I'm facing when I'm using UpdatePanel ![isssue_gif](https://imgur.com/rJeY0jW), you can see that when I select a location the parking lots multi select list loses its styles, this is what I mean with for example the multi select styles disappear, btw multi select styles uses the select2 3rd party lib.

Comment: more technically speaking, it is converting the HTML span element of the parking lots into a select element, therefore the select2 styles are rendered useless

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at this later this evening. So, using the 3rd party select2.js? Well, on page load, it runs, does some fancy foot work. The issue then is using a update panel, I think the page load client side event that select2.js uses does not run correctly, and hence everything goes sideways. That being the case, one CAN run/call the js code when using a update panel. So, I'll drop in select2, and see how to get this working in a update panel - I suspect it can be done. I suspect the client side setup script (with the jQuery selector) has to also be placed inside of the update panel.

Comment: Ok, see the proof of concept and working code. As you can see, the issue was as I suspected, that when using a update panel, the page on-ready code (client side) does not run after the post-back of the update panel. Hence with above code this issue is fixed, and as the edit part and code shows, it can be made to work just fine.